# Order of execution with setTimeout with multiple scripts?

Tags: javascript

I have an empty html page with 2 scripts:

```
  <script src="./scripta.js"></script>
  <script src="./scriptb.js"></script>
```

`scripta.js`:

```
console.log("from a")

setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("from a timeout")
}, 0)
```

`scriptb.js`

```
console.log("from b")
```

Now, when I refresh the page I mostly see  those logs in my console:

```
from a
from b
from a timeout
```

That's how it's supposed to be from my understanding.

However, after reloading page multiple times I've noticed those logs too:

```
from a
from a timeout
from b
```

Can someone explain or point me to an answer why I see the second variation of logs? Thanks.

Comment: @Dai  I don't think it's the same question.

Comment: `setTimeout` is queued until the next event loop cycle and then `scriptb.js` is being downloaded and executed as soon as it’s loaded or, if in cache, executed immediately from cache. At this point there is no guarantee which of these will finish first. This is probably what’s going on.

Comment: If *scriptb* takes longer than the timeout to load, the timer callback runs first. Not sure what's so unexpected about that. If the script fails to load entirely, the timeout would still run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a preface, remember that when browsers encounter a *plain ol' script element*, such as `<script>/* some script */</script>` or `<script src="someScript.js"></script>` then the browser *immediately* runs (or downloads-and-runs) the script - whereas if the `<script>` has a `src=""` attribute **and** has the `defer` or `async` attributes then the execution of the script will be delayed.

- <sub>(As a parenthetical: I do think it's silly that we can't use `defer` with inline scripts, though the workaround is just to wrap your code in a `DOMContentLoaded` event-listener callback).</sub>

While the spec for `setTimeout` [does guarantee *some* ordering of callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-settimeout-dev), it **does not** require that a browser run `func` immediately after a script with `setTimeout( func, 0 )` has completed.

As per my understanding of the HTML+DOM specs, the following two scenarios should be considered roughly equivalent and should always have the same results (assuming everything's cached) and have the following output:

```
foo
bar
myCallback
```

**Example 1**

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    console.log("foo");
    window.setTimeout( myCallback, 0 );
    function myCallback() {
      console.log("myCallback");
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    console.log("bar");
  </script>
</head>
</html>
```

**Example 2**

(Where `scriptA.js` and `scriptB.js` have the same script-bodies as their respective inline `<script>` in the previous example)

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="scriptA.js"></script>
  <script src="scriptB.js"></script>
</head>
</html>
```

---

In your case, the following is happening:

1. Browser downloads the page's HTML and begins parsing it.
2. When the browser encounters the first `<script src="scriptA.js"></script>` then it will pause processing the rest of the HTML until it runs `scriptA.js`.
3. The browser runs `scriptA.js` which:

   3.1. Calls `console.log("from a")`.

   3.2. The anonymous function (the `=>` fat-arrow-function that's syntactically inside the `setTimeout` call-site) is added to the browser's Task queue for execution for the next event-cycle, which generally happens *when the browser feels like it* - i.e. **it is not deterministic**:

   - A `delay` value of `0` does not mean "execute immediately" nor does it mean "execute concurrently", instead [it specifically means "execute in next event-cycle"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-settimeout-dev).
   - <sub>JavaScript in the browser is always single-threaded: concurrent execution is only possible via service-workers.</sub>

   3.3. After `scriptA.js` completes, the browser then is free to choose what to do next depending on runtime conditions (read on).
4. **Optimally**, assuming that the second `<script>` element's HTML text is already downloaded (which is almost always the case, as it's not like each HTML element is sent in its own HTTP/TCP packet) then the browser's HTML parser will then see it needs to download and run `scriptB.js` - **and** if `scriptB.js` is already cached in your browser, then the browser can execute it immediately, which means that `scriptB.js` will run before `scriptA.js`'s `setTimeout` callback.
5. However if `scriptB.js` is not already downloaded (cached, parsed and ready to execute) then the browser knows it has to wait for that first, which introduces a blocking wait, but browsers [can still use that blocking wait to run any pending JavaScript Tasks, including those added by `setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide#tasks_vs_microtasks).

---

Comment: _“I do think it's silly that we can't use `defer` with inline scripts”_ — Just use `type="module"`. Inline modules are supported and defer by default.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @SebastianSimon It's never as simple as switching to `type="module"`: it requires the script be able to run _as_ a module in the first place. A script that uses global-scope cannot run as a module. And IIRC, browsers won't run a script as a module if it doesn't have at least 1 `export` member either (I might be wrong on that, but I remember it breaking for me at some point).